# Indexing for complex predicates

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing, query-tuning

I'm struggling to identify effective indexes (or rewrite the query) to improve a query with the following confounding predicates:

- JOIN on a date from one table being in range - between two date fields on second table (one is nullable, one is not nullable in PK).
- The date used is actually the value in date field (nullable) +1.
- WHERE clauses includes OR logic on multiple flag fields.

The simplified version of the query is:

```
select
d.dim_date_id
,f.dim_provider_id
,f.dim_event_id
,d.date

from DWH.dbo.tbl_fact_outcome f
join   DWH.dbo.tbl_dim_date d on DATEADD(DAY,1,d.date) between f.known_from and f.known_to 

where
f.known_from > getdate()-12
and (d.flag_latest_day = 'Y' or  d.flag_end_of_month = 'Y'  or (d.flag_end_of_week = 'Y' AND d.flag_latest_week = 'Y'))
and d.flag_future_day = 'N'
and f.deleted = 0
```

tbl_fact_outcome has these indexes:

- PK clustered index on input_form_id, known_from
- Non-unique Nonclustered index on deleted, known_from, known_to (INCLUDES the required _dim_id fields)

tbl_dim_date has these indexes:

- PK clustered index on dim_date_id
- Non-unique nonclustered index on flag_future_day, date (INCLUDES relevant flag fields)

At present, it estimates 853 rows but returns 16,784.

Here is the query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rydKb_3AI

Statistics are up to date.
I have tried re-ordering the covering indexes but no improvement.

I'm totally stumped as to what else to try with indexes or the code itself to improve performance, so any pointers appreciated.

---

**EDIT 05/07/2020**

Ruled out following suggestions here:

- Filtered index (on deleted) on tbl_fact_outcome - less than 1% of records would be filtered out, so not worthwhile
- Filtered index (using entire WHERE clause from query) on tbl_dim_date - not possible to use OR in index
- Index on tbl_dim_date with INCLUDEd fields as key fields - tried this, made no difference, not used by optimizer.

Comment: Do you have filter conditions on your indexes or are they non-filtered indexes?

Comment: They are nonfiltered

Comment: What is the meaning of d.flag_future_day? I have bad feeling about this.

Comment: SMor - the table is a list of dates, the field flag_future_day is a Y/N flag to identify dates which are in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing all/most queries filter on `deleted` I would suggest a filtered index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TodoNewIndexName ON DWH.dbo.tbl_fact_outcome (
    known_from ASC
    ,known_to ASC
    )
INCLUDE (dim_event_id,dim_provider_id)
WHERE deleted = 0;
```

If this query is really running frequently you could also consider using a filterd index for `tbl_dim_date`. This will probably only be used by this query, since the where is an exact match of your query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TodoNewIndexName ON DWH.dbo.tbl_dim_date (DATE ASC)
    WHERE (
            d.flag_latest_day = 'Y'
            OR d.flag_end_of_month = 'Y'
            OR (
                d.flag_end_of_week = 'Y'
                AND d.flag_latest_week = 'Y'
                )
            )
        AND d.flag_future_day = 'N'
```

If you don't want a filterd index on the flag fields. You should add the flag fields to the index instead of includes.

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TodoNewIndexName ON DWH.dbo.tbl_dim_date (
    DATE ASC
    ,flag_latest_day ASC
    ,flag_end_of_month ASC
    ,flag_end_of_week ASC
    ,flag_latest_week ASC
    )
```

What this should do is get rid of the `Index Spool (Eager Spool)` [more info](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/11/sql-performance/eager-index-spool-optimizer) about eager spool.

> Eager index spools are often a sign that a useful permanent index is
> missing from the database schema. This is not always the case, as the
> streaming table-valued function examples show.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply.

Re the filtered index on tbl_fact_outcome - less than 1%  of records are flagged as deleted so in this case I don't think that would help.

The filtered index on tbl_dim_date is not possible as SQL Server doesn't allow OR conditions in filters (SQL Server 2014 doesn't at least).

I tried your final index on tbl_dim_date, but the optimizer sticks with the existing index (with those fields as INCLUDE)  and still has the eager spool.

Answer (score 0):

Has your date dimension a nextDay column or something? If not you can add this column and replace DATEADD(DAY,1,d.date)  with this new column.

Comment: It doesn't currently but that is something to consider if I can;t resolve this with indexes or query tuning.